# Is there a clustering algorithm that can cluster time series dataset based on variation ratio (or quantity)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, clustering

I am learning machine learning from scikit-learn and reading its docs.

Clustering clusters groups based on the Euclidean distance and filters them by different ways ex: Gaussian distribution, or mean-shift...etc.

But none of the clustering algorithms cluster samples based on the variation ratio.

```
EX: below every items has there sold numbers of everyday.

Item,D1,D2
A,1,5
B,10,50
C,4,70

The variation ratio below:
A:500%
B:500%
C:1750%
```

So A and B are the same group, C isn't.

Are there any clustering algorithms that can cluster time series dataset based on variation ratio (or quantity)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract features such as variation ratio
2. Cluster the extracted features instead of the raw data

Comment: That's a good solution. I found another way is to scale the value of features to [0,1]. Then cluster it. It can reach good clustering results.